# plupload height and width over 8000x8000px

Tags: php, javascript, plupload

I got a probleme with plupload when the height or the width of my image is to height(8000px * 8000px)
plupload upload the image but he return me full black after the resize.

I look for get the dimension of the image before the parsing by plupload.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be usefull to know, that to access width and heigth without thumbnail an image you can do this:

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        files = jQuery("#"+uploader.id+"_html5").get(0).files;
        jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function(e) { 
                        var image = new Image();
                        image.src = e.target.result;

                                image.onload = function() {
                                        // access image size here using this.width and this.height
                                }
                        };

                });

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx it's help me  and it's work fine !

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    files = jQuery("#"+uploader.id+"_html5").get(0).files;
    jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(e) { 
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result;
            image.onload = function() {
                if(this.width < 8000 && this.height < 8000){
                    uploader.start();
                }else{
                    var message_max_picture = "<?php echo __('Vous avez dépassé les dimensions autorisées pour l\'image '); ?>";
                    display_error_serv('Erreur', message_max_picture, '');
                    uploader.removeFile(myfile);
                }
            }
        };
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```